# Is there any way to import a variable from a function in another file without using return in Python?

Tags: python, function, pygame, return

I have this pygame code which is divided into multiple files and in one of the files I want to import a variable from a function which is in another file.

```
# gamescreen.py
highscore = 0
def game_screen(screen):
    ...

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, world_sprites, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
    if len(hits) > 0:
        if score > highscore:
            global highscore
            highscore = score
            state = PLAYAGAIN
    ...

    return state
```

```
# playagain.py
def play_again(screen):
    ...

    highscore_texto = font.render('highscore: {0}'.format(highscore), True, (BLACK))
    background.blit(highscore_texto, (30, 25))
    ...
```

Is there any way I can acess that highscore variable in the file playagain.py without having to return it in the game_screen function?

When I tried to return it in the game_screen function like this:

```
return state, highscore
```

And access it in the playagain.py file like this:

```
game_screen(screen)[1]
```

It just ran the game_screen function two times, which is not what I want because it messes up my game.

Comment: Declare `highscore` as `global` in your function where you change it and then `from gamescreen import highscore`. Also, doing what you described with returning a tuple containing `(state, highscore)` and accessing it with `game_screen(screen)[1]` will not call the function twice so I think you're confusing something or something else is going on - unless you meant that you added an _additional_ call to `game_screen` to return the value which will of course result in the function being called twice

Comment: @awarrier99 - `import highscore from gamescreen` is not valid syntax and `from gamestream import highscore` won't work because it wouldn't see the updates to the variable.

Comment: @tdelaney yup I realized the first part and already edited that - made a weird mix with JavaScript for a second

Comment: @awarrier99 I did call the game_screen in other file, forgot to mention that, that’s probably why it didn’t work. I'm already declaring highscore as global. When I import it from gamescreen, it justs imports the line `highscore = 0` that was writeen before the function in the file gamescreen.py

Comment: Ah ok gotcha, yeah I posted about using `global` and then only realized you had already done that once it was too late to edit the comment. Sounds like tdelaney's answer solved your problem though (by the way make sure to mark the answer as accepted to resolve the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import gamestream
print(gamestream.highscore)
```

The variable is set in the module namespace (confusingly named "global" when its really "module global"). Import the module and you've got its namespace.

This doesn't work

```
from gamestream import highscore
```

In that case you rebound the current thing in highscore to your module's namespace and it won't see changes to the original. It is the same as if you had done

```
import gamestream
highscore = gamestream.highscore
```

A new variable called "highscore" is created in the local module and the current value in `gamestream.highscore` is bound to it. If `gamestream.highscore` is reassigned, that wouldn't affect this separate variable.